# Grant execute to stored procedure without SELECT permissions to underlying table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, permissions

I don't think this is possible, but I hope I am missing something. Let's say I have this stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 SP3:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc] 
AS 
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[mytable]
```

I want to grant a database principal the permission to execute `[myproc]` without granting the permission to `SELECT` on the underlying table.

I have tried all sorts of `GRANT` statements with no luck. When I execute `myproc`, I still get the error

> select permission denied on mytable

The database principal is not the DB Owner and I do not want to make him the DB Owner.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is: who owns the table and who owns the procedure? If the two are different, you are probably running afoul of ownership chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weicher,
Unless there's a specific deny on the underlying table this grant statement should work:

```
GRANT Exec [dbo].[myproc] TO MyUser;
GO
```

Test it with code like this:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'MyUser';
GO
EXEC [dbo].[myproc]; -- should work
GO
SELECT id FROM [dbo].[table]; -- should fail
GO
REVERT;
```

When I've changed code six ways to Sunday, I like to start clean to make sure I didn't bollix something in inadvertently and be very purposeful. step. by. step.

1. Make a test table, Grant MyUser read rights - can you run a select
   using the execute as user code?
2. Remove read rights, does the select work?
   If it didn't, the world is still sane (somewhat). Now try with a new stored procedure
3. Grant execute rights to MyUser - does it work?

If it does, then follow the same test on the actual table - Can you grant read rights, then can read rights be removed. If so recreate the SP and try again.

And sorry if that was too simplistic, no offense intended just wanted to make sure we were on the same page testing wise.

If it doesn't work, post the results of the test and I'll try to help further.

Comment: Good answer but I think this is missing the `ON` keyword when granting permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make the DB Principle the owner then you need to grant it permissions with 'Grant With' in order to have them passed on further.

Assuming 'dbo' is the owner and 'ElevatedUser' is a new user with select permissions

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[myproc] TO ElevatedUser 
WITH GRANT OPTION  AS [dbo]

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[myproc] TO MyUser AS ElevatedUser
```

or if you are really stuck you can put it inside the stored procedure itself

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc] 
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo' 
AS
BEGIN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SPNAME TO DBUSER
```